# Django admin - list_filter strange bug

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm facing this strange bug/issue in my app. http://d.pr/i/bRp7

When I filter my list with orders, it seems that filter is applied well (it's really 13 orders from 30), but the results r not in the view.

On my local machine it works fine.

Do you guys have any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are passing pagination objects to template.

You need to do (Suppose you are getting "Orders" Pagination objects in Django HTML templates.)

```
{% for order in Orders.object_list %}
    {{ order }}
{% endfor %}
```

In Looping Order, You will get display order.

Comment: Check how to pass object_list in context in django ( grappelli's )